# Word that denotes number of numbers by which a number can be divided without a remainder

Tags: terminology, divisibility

Is there a word that denotes the number of numbers by which a number can be divided without a remainder?

That is,

- for 12 ***it*** is 4 (because 12 can be divided by 2, 3, 4, 6),
- and for 14 ***it*** is 2 (because 14 can be divided only by 2 and 7).

Is there a word for this ***it***?

Comment: A single word? Probably not. Just "number of proper divisors."

Comment: @Sean, $1$ is a proper divisor as well, so it'd have to be "one less than the number of proper divisors".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of divisors function, sometimes denoted $\tau$ (tau) includes $1$ and $n$ as divisors also. So for instance $\tau(12)=6$ (divisors are $1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12$.)

Answer (score 1):

This "it" is called the **number** of **factors** or **divisors** of a number.

As said in the comments however, I don't think there is a singular word that describes this.